# Why truncated text no work in my flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div,
ul,
li {
  display: flex;
}

#A,
ul {
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}

#A {
  width: 130px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

span {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 0;
}

#B {
  order: 0;
}

#D {
  order: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#C {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
  <div id="B">
    <span>123456789012</span>
  </div>
  <ul id="C">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  <a id="D" href="google.com">google</a>
</div>
```

You can also try my code at https://jsfiddle.net/w8h17f2d/

After the code ran, it turns out to be this:

[image]

Actually, I want to achieve this:
[image]

You may ask why the HTML like this for I am coding a Responsive Website. The code above is for mobile site and on PC site it will like this:

[image]

How can I solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In span change `min-width` to `max-width` and set `width`.

```
span {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your div flow direction to row and add max width on span. See below example.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div,
ul,
li {
  display: flex;
}

#A,
ul {
  flex-direction: row;
  width:100%;
}
#A{
  display: flse;
  flex-direction: row;
  width:130px;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
span {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 80px;
}
#B{
  order:0;
}
#D{
  order:1;
  margin-left:auto;
}
#C{
  order:2;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
<div id="B">
<span>123456789012</span>
</div>
<ul id="C">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
<a id="D" href="google.com">google</a>
</div>
```